# ActiveRecord: Comparing a belongs_to association without database call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to compare an associated belongs_to record with an existing record and not hit the database? For example, I have a User, and want to see if an Account belongs to the User. The simple way is `account.user == user`, but that loads the account's user from the database and then compares it will `user`. The DB call is:

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Alternately, although it's undocumented, it looks like I can do `user.accounts.include?(account)`, but that calls:

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM `accounts`  WHERE `accounts `.`user_id` = 1 AND `accounts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Of course, I could just do `account.user_id == user.id`, but that doesn't feel very "railsy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because Rails relations are lazy loaded by default; the accounts table row in the database only contains the `user_id` column and that all what it knows about the user but whenever you need to call `account.user` a separate database query will be made to get other `User` columns than `id` to compare that with different `User` objects.

Comment: Bummer. Would be nice if `account.user` provided a relation that could be compared to another user object without hitting the db.